# python grid control / spreadsheet

Tags: python, gridview, spreadsheet

I am designing a thick-client (i.e. non-browser) Python application that will communicate with a hosted database.  One of the screens of this application needs to have a grid / spreadsheet area that allows presentation of many rows of data, filtering, sorting, and updating of multiple rows of information.  Does anyone have a recommendation for an open-source UI control in Python that has this capability?

** Note - It must be platform-indepedent: will likely be deployed on Mac and Windows clients. **

Thank you!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good results with [wxPython's CSheet](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.sheet.CSheet-class.html), though I ended up modifying it somewhat so that it acted a little more "Excel-like" (arrow keys and context menu) as per a coworker's request.  wxPython works on OS X but it's 32-bit only right now I believe (based on Carbon API).

Comment: Thanks!  One quick question related to using CSheet.  I want to automatically update the database each time a row of data is changed (but not each time one cell in a row is changed - that would be too frequent), and I want to have a log of the changes stored in the database as well (old values and new values).  Taking a quick look at the methods of CSheet, I THINK the right approach is to use a flag in the OnCellChange method implementation noting that something has changed, and then when the user moves focus to a new row, check that flag and then update the database accordingly.  Correct?

Comment: @Ron - if I'm following what you'd like to do, you might want to check out the cell editors in the [sheet module](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.sheet-module.html), e.g. [CTextEditor](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.sheet.CTextCellEditor-class.html).  You could look for a wx.EVT_CHAR event on the cell text editor and look for the down arrow or Enter key with key=evt.GetKeyCode() in its OnChar(self, evt) method.